# Safari allow text to scale based on mobile Text size

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, mobile-safari

I'm seeing an issue with iphone Safari not responding to Text size changes made on device (settings->Display & brightness->text size).
Trying with text-size-adjust property in css. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust

Chrome seems to scale text correctly when Text size is changed on device. Is there any other property needed to get it working on an iphone Safari?

https://jsfiddle.net/pey8b4ct/2

```
<style>
    body {
        -ms-text-size-adjust: auto;
        -moz-text-size-adjust: auto;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: auto;
    }
</style>
<div>
  <label>Some text box</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
<p>
Some paragraph we need to take into account
</p>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Some text box2</label>
<input type="text">
</div>
enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like adding style `font: -apple-system-body;` fixes the issue, now safari scales as  needed too. One other thing is font-size should be in em, wont scale if it's in px.
More details below
https://ind.ie/labs/blog/dynamic-type-support/